# angular: isolating directive instance variables from parent controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the need to create a directive or set of directives that allow my users to set options for IMEs (input method editors) on my site. IMEs are virtual keyboards, transliteration APIs, basically tools to help you type in a different alphabet than your OS's settings. The user has the need to use TWO languages on the site, and must toggle between them on the inputs and text areas. The user sets his IME choice for each language, which is 'global', in the InputController, and then toggles between languages for each element, which is 'local', and the state should be distinct for each input/textarea element.

```
app.directive('dynamicInput', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            inputlang: "=inputlang"
        },
        controller: 'InputController',
        link: function(scope, element){
            element[0].onfocus = function(){
                scope.attachToField(element[0].id, scope.inputlang);
            };
            element[0].onclick = function(){
                scope.attachToField(element[0].id, scope.inputlang);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

That's the attribute directive for input and textarea elements that directs the InputController to enable the IMEs on the element. As you can see, the input lang is determined by the parent, which is a sort of "dummy" directive I used to bounce the input lang from one of its children to the other. inputlang is set with this directive, "lang-selector"

```
app.directive('langSelector', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/angular/templates/lang-selector.html",
        scope: {
            inputlang: "="
        },
    };
});
```

And its template:

```
<div>
    <div id="kb_opt_wrapper" class="flexrow spread">
        <div class="tc pointer" ng-click="inputlang = 'en'" ng-class="inputlang == 'en' ? 'red' : 'black'">
            <div class="true-center">
            </div>
            <div class="testbk ">
                English
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tc pointer" ng-click="inputlang = 'ar'">
            <div class="testbk" ng-class="inputlang == 'ar' ? 'red' : 'black'">
                Arabic
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, there's the dummy parent directive, dynamic-field, with a child scope.

```
app.directive('dynamicField', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: true,
    };
});
```

So the final implementation would look like this:

```
<dynamic-field>
    <textarea inputlang="inputlang" dynamic-input id="commentfield" ></textarea>
    <lang-selector inputlang="inputlang"></lang-selector>
</dynamic-field>
```

So this basically works fine until it is nested twice in another directive. The inputlang bubbles up to the parent controller and then binds to its other sibling. Then the state is no longer distinct for each element. Clicking "ar" on one lang-selector changes it on the other directives within the same parent. Furthermore, I need to be able to access to value of the dynamic-input element from outside the dynamic-field, (using ng-model or the like) so making the dynamic-input/dynamic-field scope completely inaccessible from the parents would just create another problem. How can I pick and choose?

Comment: Could you provide more detail about what you mean by "until it is nested twice in another directive"? Maybe an example of the markup with multiple uses of the directives.